# "Unable to locate application file [program name].msi "Error after reboot

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Is there any way that we can avoid getting this error? Some people say that it's because the msi file gets cleared after reboot, which is why setup.exe can't find that msi file from %TEMP% folder. So, what can I do to make sure that msi file will still be there after system reboot? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you save it in a different location?

Comment: hmm, I am not quite sure how. I am using MakeSFX to combine setup.exe and msi into 1 exe file btw.

Comment: I didn't use MakeSFX, but i would check for a way to choose a destination folder when creating the sfx file or when extracting it

Comment: Does your install image consist of two files? Can't you specify a parameter to MakeSFX so that it does not remove the extracted files?